# Handling JSON Object With jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having trouble handling a JSON object that I'm getting back from an AJAX request.

It's a simple flat JSON object, and all I want to do is write the responses back onto the page.

Can anyone point out how to loop over these objects and output the values? I just keep getting `[undefined]` or `[object]` written

Code here:

```
$.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "func/chatResponse.php",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function() {  
            $.getJSON('func/chatResponse.php?a=jsonLatest', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index) {
                    //items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                    $('body').append('<li id="' + data.user + '">' + data.user + '</li>');
                    alert(data);
                 });
            });
            alert("done");
          }  
        });
```

**JSON sample here**

```
[
    {"user":"someguy","message":"my message","timestamp":"2011-04-19 17:26:09"},
    {"user":"Cheyne","message":"Hey There ...  Nice site","timestamp":"2011-04-19 17:26:09"}
]
```

Comment: It looks like data is an array. Try data[index].user

Comment: I love stackoverflow,  I got multiple answers within minutes.  thanks guys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`data` is the **array**, while you want the **items inside the array**.

`$.each` doesn't change `data` to become the items, instead it passes individual items as the second parameter to the function you supply:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    // Use item in here
    $('body').append('<li id="' + item.user + '">' + item.user + '</li>');
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `data[index]`:

```
$.each(data, function (index) {
    // use data[index] in here
    $('body').append('<li id="' + data[index].user + '">' + data[index].user + '</li>');
});
```

---

By the way, avoid ugly string concatenation with:

```
$('<li>', {id: item.user, text: item.user}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this.    Although im getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  on the body.append line.  Any ideas ?

Comment: @Cheyne, can you paste the exact line that you have?

Comment: $.each(data, function(index)               
                    alert(data[index].user);
                 });

Comment: Wait , i was missing a brace...   Fixed it now..  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
                 $.each(data, function(index) {
                    //items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                    $('body').append('<li id="' + data[index].user + '">' + data[index].user + '</li>');
                    alert(data);
                 });
```

Comment: $.each passes in the item in the array (`data[index]`) as a second param to your function, so you don't need to access it like that.

Comment: I don't know much jQuery, I was just stating the obvious here :) But it looks like there are much better solutions, so...